# Handle error when putting an object on amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, error-handling

I am very new in nodejs. I use this code to upload files to an amazone S3.

```
s3.putObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: key,
            Body: content
          }, (res) => {
console.log("One file added");
  });
```

How can I handle an error if the upload of one file fails?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in the official documentation, just read it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

```
s3.putObject({
    Bucket : bucketName,
    Key : key,
    Body : content
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("One file added");
});
```